# Cakephp controller name

Tags: php, cakephp

i m new to cakephp. i have stuck in one place the problem is 
table name - india_tends
controller - tends
model name - india_tends

The problem is that cake php not allow tends to controller name its show that i have to use india_tends.. so any way to give tends to controller name?

Comment: You should really stick to the core principles of CakePHP in that your tables are plurals and your other stack follows the trend. http://book.cakephp.org/view/901/CakePHP-Conventions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the variable `$useTable="india_tends"`  and `$name="tends"`  in model

Answer (score 1):

If your table name is `india_tends`, then your controller code should be in the file `india_tends_controller.php`, and the class name should be `IndiaTendsController`.

In your case I think you want the `IndiaTendsController` to be accessible through `/tends/:actions` so the best guess would be using `routing`.

Edit your `config/routes.php` to have the following code:

```
Router::connect('/tends/*', array('controller' => 'india_tends'));
```

And you can have it accessible through /tends/*

Answer (score 0):

Which version of CakePHP are you using?
You could use [routing](http://book.cakephp.org/view/945/Routes-Configuration).

Comment: I would strongly suggest upgrading if possible.

Comment: @David: Your suggestion doesn't make much sense to me, he is already using the latest (stable) version of CakePHP.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry ignore me. I'm confused. It must be due to a chronic lack of caffeine. *goes to fix*